# How to draw bracket trees in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw bracket trees in tikz?

for example

```
          bob {dave
               eve
alice {              francis
          carol -- { grace
                     hans
```

Comment: Did you consult the pgf-manual?

Comment: Please extend your pseudo code to an MWE (without brackets) .

Answer (score 21):

Do you need `TiKZ`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\text{Alice} 
\begin{cases}
    \text{Bob}  
        \begin{cases} \text{Dave} \\ \text{Eve} \end{cases}\\[5mm]
    \text{Carol}  
    \begin{cases} \text{Francis} \\ \text{Grace} \\ \text{Hans}\end{cases}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for doing it with simple tools. If I were you , I would add some vertical spacing between the two inner cases.

Comment: @Bernard You're right. I've done it!

Answer (score 11):

with `forest` and `tikz`, on very complex way ...

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\tikzset{
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        thick,
        pen colour={red}},  % <--- you can change to desired color
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    align= left,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    edge = {draw=none},
    anchor = west,
    tier/.option = level,
    grow'= 0,
    l sep= 3mm,
    s sep= 4mm}
[Alice
    [Bob, name=b
        [Dave\\ eve, name=de]
    ]
    [Carol, name=c
        [Francis\\ Grace\\ Henry, name=fgh]
    ]
]
\draw[BC=1mm/mirror]   (b.north west)   -- (c.south west);
\draw[BC=1mm/mirror]   (de.north west)  -- (de.south west);
\draw[BC=1mm/mirror]   (fgh.north west) -- (fgh.south west);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it worth to write such complex code? ;-)

Comment: I like this because all the braces have uniform thickness. (+1)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution with `forest` using `forked edge`s and `rounded corners` to make the braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest} 
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, forked edge, text width=8mm, edge=rounded corners, l sep=3mm, fork sep=1mm}
[Alice[Bob[Dave][Eve]][Carol[Frances][Grace, no edge][Hans]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image] Missed the bracket piece, sorry, but here is what I came up with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicefrac}



\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate [label=left: Alice] (O) at (0,0);
        \coordinate [label=right: Bob] (A0) at (2,1.5);
        \coordinate [label=right: Carol](B0) at (2,-1.5);
            \draw (O)--(A0);
            \draw (O)--(B0);
        \coordinate (A1) at (3.2,1.5);
        \coordinate (B1) at (3.2,-1.5);
        
        \coordinate [label=right: Dave] (AA1) at (5,2);
        \coordinate [label=right: Eve](BB1) at (5,1);
            \draw (A1)--(AA1);
            \draw (A1)--(BB1);
        \coordinate[label=right: Francis] (BA1) at (5,0);
        \coordinate[label=right: Hans] (BB1) at (5,-3);
        \coordinate[label=right: Grace] (CC1) at (5,-1.5);
            \draw (B1)--(BA1);
            \draw (B1)--(BB1);
            \draw (B1)--(CC1);
            
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```